# XAMLParseException was unhandled at InitializeComponent()

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I am developing my project in .net framework 4.0 using wpf.
Following is the  XAML code for crystal report viewer.

```
<Window x:Class="KhataBahi.GenerateReports"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer;assembly=SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer"
        Title="GenerateReports" Height="600" Width="550">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,2,-1">
        <Button x:Name="Back" Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="198,522,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" Click="Back_Click"/>
        <my:CrystalReportsViewer x:Name="KhataBahiAMReportsViewer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="490"/>

    </Grid>
```

However, its giving following exception at InitializeComponent();

On looking for a solution to this problem it was suggested that this happens because you have to explicity tell the compiler to support old .Net dll’s into the .Net 4.0 runtime.So, I added the following to my app.config file

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" >
    <supportedRuntime version= "v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

but the compiler always show message like this

So, further I went to the properties of dotnetconfig40.xsd and edited the startup as

```
<xs:element name="startup" vs:help="configuration/startup">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:element name="requiredRuntime" vs:help="configuration/startup/requiredRuntime">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
                    <xs:attribute name="safemode" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="supportedRuntime" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" vs:help="configuration/startup/supportedRuntime">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
                    <xs:attribute name="sku" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:attribute name="useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />
        <!-- see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h.aspx -->
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This removed the warnings but the exception till persists.
I even tried to bind the assemblies explicitly in app.config

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns ="clr-namespace:SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer;assembly=SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer">
      <probing privatePath="C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

But, no luck. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Might it be because of the missing quotes at `xmlns:x=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml`?

Comment: I tried that as well but its still giving the same exception.

Comment: @JeffRSon Its showing an XAML Parse Exception stating: "The invocation of the constructor on type 'SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.ViewerCore' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception. "

Comment: Are there nested InnerExceptions? What is `ViewerCore`? Look there, why there's an exception.

Comment: InnerException states: "The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils' threw an exception."

Comment: here ViewerCore is for Crystal Reports Viewer. While the window tries to initialis components it throws the exception and fails loading the crystal report viewer.

Answer (score 0):

You have no `" "` in your namespace for `x`. Also , check for the **Inner Exception**

```
<Window x:Class="KhataBahi.GenerateReports"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer;assembly=SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer"
    Title="GenerateReports" Height="600" Width="550">
<Grid Margin="0,0,2,-1">
    <Button x:Name="Back" Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="198,522,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" Click="Back_Click"/>
    <my:CrystalReportsViewer x:Name="KhataBahiAMReportsViewer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="490"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I have checked the inner exception its an XAML Parse Exception saying: "The invocation of the constructor on type 'SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.ViewerCore' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception."

Comment: There should be more to that. Was it trying to say it can't resolve something to its constructor?

Comment: InnerException states: "The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils' threw an exception."

Comment: There should be another inner for that. :)